# How to download a file in Bazel from a BUILD file?

Tags: build, bazel, bazel-rules

Is there a way to download a file in Bazel directly from a BUILD file? I know I can probably use `wget` and enable networking, but I'm looking for a solution that would work with `bazel fetch`.

I have a bunch of files to download that are going to be consumed by just a single package. It feels wrong to use the standard approach of adding a `http_file()` rule in `WORKSPACE` at the monorepo root. It would be decoupled from the package and it would pollute a totally unrelated file.

Comment: Quite to the contrary, putting external dependencies into `WORKSPACE` file is exactly the correct place. You can split it into multiple `.bzl` files and load functions/macros instantiating those repo rules if you're concerned about visually cluttering single `WORKSPACE` file.

Answer (score 0):

Create a `download.bzl` and load it in your `WORKSPACE` file

*WORKSPACE*:

```
load("//my_project/my_sub_project:download.bzl", "downlad_files")
load("@bazel_skylib//rules:copy_file.bzl", "copy_file")

download_files()
```

*download.bzl*:

```
BUILD_FILE_CONTENT_some_3d_model = """
filegroup(
    name = "some_3d_model",
    srcs = [
        "BMW_315_DA2.obj",
    ],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
"""

def download_files():
    http_archive(
        name = "some_3d_model",
        build_file_content = BUILD_FILE_CONTENT_some_3d_model,
        #sha256 = "...",
        urls = ["https://vertexwahn.de/lfs/v1/some_3d_model.zip"],
    )

copy_file(
    name = "copy_resources_some_3d_model",
    src = "@some_3d_model",
    out = "my/destination/path/some_file.obj",
)
```

Comment: How is this useful without explaining what to put in download.bzl, or at least giving a pointer to an example?

Comment: @JayEye Thanks for the hint - modified my answer!